# Channel Videos - Dev Demon

Tags: devdemon, channel-videos

Is it possible to remove "related videos" when the video has finished playing?

I know this is possible when using the embed directly, just wondered if i could replicate it with channel videos.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of features you can turn on and off in the module control panel.

[image: Channel Videos Control Panel]

Comment: Yes however I can't see the feature to turn off related videos? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Set "rel" to `0`.